# A question about customizing ref in enumitem package

Tags: lists, cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem

I'm experimenting with **enumitem** version 3.4 (released Aug 2011) a little but facing a problem in customizing the `ref`.

What I'm trying to reach is simple: Have list label in the form **1.1.3.** for example. This is easy using the `label*` key. However, I don't want the references to take the same form as the label. This is because the **dot** (.) at the end is inconvenient to appear in the middle of a sentence.

So I defined the list as follows:

```
\newlist{procedureflow}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[procedureflow,1]{label*=\color{blue!80!black}\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[procedureflow,2]{label*=\color{green!80!black}\arabic*.,ref=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}
```

The problem with the above code is that the part `ref=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*` evaluates using the current value of `enumi` which of course has nothing to do with the list that is yet to come later in the source file   :(

Here is the code in which the list is created:

```
\begin{procedureflow}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \begin{procedureflow}
         \item First First
         \item Second Second\label{mylabel}
    \end{procedureflow}
\end{procedureflow}
Here is a cross reference: \ref{mylabel}
```

There are similar examples in the user guide of enumitem (chapter 5, page 9), so I wonder how could I use the `ref` key to have the reference displayed as **1.1.3** (i.e. without a **dot** at the end)? (I feel something is not right in `enumitem` in that regard! At least the example seems not useful to me)

Comment: The problem might be different from what I thought; it seems that enumi is not used in my list (procedureflow). Probably I need to define a corresponding counter? Rechecking user guide...

Comment: YES! The "enumi" counter is not used in my newly defined procedureflow! So how to customize its ref??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I build a minimal example with your code fragment.

```
\listfiles
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{procedureflow}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[procedureflow,1]{label*=\color{blue!80!black}\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[procedureflow,2]{label*=\color{green!80!black}\arabic*.,ref=\arabic{procedureflowi}.\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\begin{procedureflow}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \begin{procedureflow}
         \item First First
         \item Second Second\label{mylabel}
    \end{procedureflow}
\end{procedureflow}
Here is a cross reference: \ref{mylabel}
\end{document}
```

With this version

```
enumitem.sty 2011/08/06 v3.4 Customized lists
```

You have to use the correct counter: `procedureflowi`
[image]

Comment: Thanks Marco! I didn't find it clear in the user guide though, but it works anyway :)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not clear, but rather it's not--period :-). I'll explain it in a next release.

Comment: Such a nice suggestion....love it....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
\newlist{procedureflow}{enumerate}{3}     
\setlist[procedureflow]{label*={\color{blue!60!red}\arabic*.},ref=\arabic*}     
\setlist[procedureflow,2]{label*={\color{green!80!black}\arabic*.}}
```

Comment: But using your code the references will also have colors and this could not be desirable.