# Defining a new list with enumitem that uses ref from surrounding environment

Tags: lists, theorems, enumitem, amsthm

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Great result]
  \label{th:great}
  Let 1 be the number one.
  Then:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), ref={\ref{th:great}.\alph*}]
    \item if $x=1$ and $y=x$, then $y=1$;
          \label{th:x-eq-y}
    \item if $x<1$ and $y=x$, then $y<1$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Lesser result]
  \label{th:lesser}
  Let 0 be the number zero.
  Then:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), ref={\ref{th:lesser}.\alph*}]
    \item if $x=0$ and $y=x$, then $y=0$;
          \label{th:other}
    \item if $x<0$ and $y=x$, then $y<0$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Wow, that Theorem~\ref{th:great} was great.
Proving Theorem~\ref{th:x-eq-y} was particularly challenging, much more than Theorem~\ref{th:other}.
\end{document}
```

It works as expected.

How can I define a new list with `\newlist`/`\setlist` so that the ref is set appropriately depending on the ref of the surrounding `theorem` environment?

Ideally I would like to be able to write just

```
\begin{theorem}[Great result]
  \label{th:great}
  Let 1 be the number one.
  Then:
  \begin{thenumerate}
    \item if $x=1$ and $y=x$, then $y=1$;
          \label{th:x-eq-y}
    \item if $x<1$ and $y=x$, then $y<1$.
  \end{thenumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

And get `\ref{th:x-eq-y}` produce "1.a".

**Related**: [A question about customizing ref in enumitem package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26665/36686)

Comment: `\thecountername`? [Not literally - substitute the name of the counter, of course.]

Comment: And if somebody answers the 'bonus', will you accept their answer, rejecting egreg's? Or will you stick with egreg's, rejecting theirs? Your question should be of a kind such that you can select a single answer on a reasonable basis. This looks like a follow-up question to me. Remember: one question per question.

Comment: In fact I think @egreg answered the bonus in the comments. I'll remove the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\thetheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{thenumerate}[1][]
 {\enumerate[label=\alph*\textup{)},ref=\thetheorem.\alph*),#1]}
 {\endenumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Great result]
\label{th:great}
Let $1$ be the number one. Then:
\begin{thenumerate}
\item\label{th:x-eq-y} if $x=1$ and $y=x$, then $y=1$;
\item if $x<1$ and $y=x$, then $y<1$.
\end{thenumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Lesser result]
\label{th:lesser}
Let $0$ be the number zero. Then:
\begin{thenumerate}
\item\label{th:other} if $x=0$ and $y=x$, then $y=0$;
\item if $x<0$ and $y=x$, then $y<0$.
\end{thenumerate}
\end{theorem}

Wow, that Theorem~\ref{th:great} was great. Proving Theorem~\ref{th:x-eq-y} was 
particularly challenging, much more than Theorem~\ref{th:other}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

So long as you number theorem-like environments based on the `theorem` environment, say with

```
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

there will be no problem in inheriting the correct number.

The following variation also copes with different counters for the different environments. It will go wrong if there's an explicit `\refstepcounter` at the same level (which shouldn't generally happen).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{thenumerate}[1][]
 {\edef\thistheorem{\@currentlabel}%
  \enumerate[label=\alph*\textup{)},ref=\thistheorem.\alph*),#1]}
 {\endenumerate}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Great result]
\label{th:great}
Let $1$ be the number one. Then:
\begin{thenumerate}
\item\label{th:x-eq-y} if $x=1$ and $y=x$, then $y=1$;
\item if $x<1$ and $y=x$, then $y<1$.
\end{thenumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}[Lesser result]
\label{th:lesser}
Let $0$ be the number zero. Then:
\begin{thenumerate}
\item\label{th:other} if $x=0$ and $y=x$, then $y=0$;
\item if $x<0$ and $y=x$, then $y<0$.
\end{thenumerate}
\end{lemma}

Wow, that Theorem~\ref{th:great} was great. Proving Theorem~\ref{th:x-eq-y} was 
particularly challenging, much more than Lemma~\ref{th:other}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) would you use the parenthesis in the ref too? 2) Is there a simple way to adapt this to be usable with other kinds of theorems without needing to define a new list for each kind?

Comment: @Bordaigorl (1) Definitely not. (2) Since you won't be numbering the other theorems separately, there is no problem.

Comment: but would `\thetheorem` hold the right counter even inside a, say, lemma?

Comment: @Bordaigorl If you have `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}` that's what happens. If you use separate numbering for theorems, lemmas, corollaries and propositions, you're not thinking to your readers who won't have clues for finding them.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand what you meant. I agree with your comment on numbering but sometimes you do not have control on that.

Comment: @Bordaigorl, you can also just locally reconfigure `enumerate`, see my addition to @egregs answer below.

Comment: @Bordaigorl I added the way for differently numbered environments.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an addition to egregs answer. There is no reason to use an extra env for this. Just add the extra configuration whenever we are inside a `theorem` env. Downside: this has to be added to every thm like env.

I use this to control that enumerates are formatted consistently in teaching materials etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem,etoolbox}
\SetEnumitemKey{:thmrefs}{
  label=\alph*\textup{)},
  ref=\thetheorem.\alph*)
}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{
  \setlist*[enumerate]{:thmrefs}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Great result]
\label{th:great}
Let $1$ be the number one. Then:
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{th:x-eq-y} if $x=1$ and $y=x$, then $y=1$;
\item if $x<1$ and $y=x$, then $y<1$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Lesser result]
\label{th:lesser}
Let $0$ be the number zero. Then:
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{th:other} if $x=0$ and $y=x$, then $y=0$;
\item if $x<0$ and $y=x$, then $y<0$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Wow, that Theorem~\ref{th:great} was great. Proving Theorem~\ref{th:x-eq-y} was 
particularly challenging, much more than Theorem~\ref{th:other}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice trick! Great for consistency. Thanks!