# How to obtain a letter in a cross reference / list counter with letters (alph)?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, cleveref

I´d like to obtain this
[image]

How can you obtain letter instead a number in a cross reference (label/ref) in an enumitem (alph) ref/label?

Or any solution with the fantastic cleverref package?.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

%\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}


\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}) }
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question \label{sumas} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{sumas-cinco} $5+5+5=$
    \item \label{sumas-nueve} $9+9+9+9=$
\end{enumerate}

You can see at \ref{mult} \ref{mult-cinco} a faster version of \ref{sumas} \ref{sumas-cinco}.


\question \label{mult} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{mult-cinco} $3\cdot5=$
    \item \label{mult-nueve} $4\cdot9=$
\end{enumerate}

The exercise \ref{mult} is a faster versión of \ref{sumas}.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `enumitem`, don't redefine `\labelenumi` but use the user interface of the package, e.g., either:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

%\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\alph{*})}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question \label{sumas} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{sumas-cinco} $5+5+5=$
    \item \label{sumas-nueve} $9+9+9+9=$
\end{enumerate}

You can see at \ref{mult} \ref{mult-cinco} a faster version of \ref{sumas} \ref{sumas-cinco}.


\question \label{mult} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{mult-cinco} $3\cdot5=$
    \item \label{mult-nueve} $4\cdot9=$
\end{enumerate}

The exercise \ref{mult} is a faster versión of \ref{sumas}.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image: 2 a) 1 a)]

or

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

%\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\alph{*}),ref=\alph{*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question \label{sumas} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{sumas-cinco} $5+5+5=$
    \item \label{sumas-nueve} $9+9+9+9=$
\end{enumerate}

You can see at \ref{mult} \ref{mult-cinco} a faster version of \ref{sumas} \ref{sumas-cinco}.


\question \label{mult} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{mult-cinco} $3\cdot5=$
    \item \label{mult-nueve} $4\cdot9=$
\end{enumerate}

The exercise \ref{mult} is a faster versión of \ref{sumas}.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image: 2 a 1 a]

See [the `enumitem` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) section 2 “Quick reference” for a similar example and section 3.1 “Label and cross references format” for the documentation of `label=<commands>` and `ref=<commands>`.

If references to the enumerations inside questions always should include the question number, you also can do something like:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

%\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\alph{*})}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question \label{sumas} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\ref{sumas}\alph{*}]% use a label to show the question number
    \item \label{sumas-cinco} $5+5+5=$
    \item \label{sumas-nueve} $9+9+9+9=$
\end{enumerate}

You can see at \ref{mult-cinco} a faster version of \ref{sumas-cinco}.


\question \label{mult} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\thequestion\alph{*}]% use the question number directly
    \item \label{mult-cinco} $3\cdot5=$
    \item \label{mult-nueve} $4\cdot9=$
\end{enumerate}

The exercise \ref{mult} is a faster versión of \ref{sumas}.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know about the bad code \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})} but not about the consecuencesof not obtaining the letter. Thank you.

Comment: What a excelent answer!

Comment: Are there a way to refer to exercise 2a) with an only label (without using a lbaelin the questioin and another in the enumerated list)?

Comment: @MikaIke [For a follow-up question you should ask a new question.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/277964) However, see the last `enumerate` environment in the last example and add the wanted `)` before the existing `]`. If you want this for *all* `enumerate` environments, you can copy the option to a `\setlist` command in the document preamble.

Comment: @MikaIke But before asking a follow-up question see, e.g., [Defining a new list with enumitem that uses ref from surrounding environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215907/277964)

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be making use of the machinery of the `enumitem` package. If this impression is correctl, you need to redefine both `\theenumi` and `\labelenumi` yourself. For good measure, I'd also redefine the "prefix macro", `\p@enumi`, to simplify creating cross-refernences to level-1 items.

Observe that I would *not* include `)` in the cross-reference "number".

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{\thequestion}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question \label{sumas} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{sumas-cinco} $5+5+5=$
    \item \label{sumas-nueve} $9+9+9+9=$
\end{enumerate}

\question \label{mult} Calculate:
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item \label{mult-cinco} $3\cdot5=$
    \item \label{mult-nueve} $4\cdot9=$
\end{enumerate}
\end{questions}

\noindent
You can see that \ref{mult-cinco} is faster than \ref{sumas-cinco}.

\noindent
Exercise \ref{mult} is a faster version of exercise \ref{sumas}.
\end{document}
```